# Cache html ignoring query string

Tags: http, service-worker, http-caching

On my site, I use query string parameters to pass information to the Javascript, but the actual html returned is independent of the query string (it is just a template which is filled in dynamically by Javascript).

Is there any easy way to get the page cached independent of query string parameters? One idea I had was to use a service worker to strip query strings from requests, but I was wondering if there was any simpler and cleaner approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just cache the non-query-parameters page and then, when responding to a `fetch` event, pass an additional option to `cache.match(request, options)` call:

```js
return cache.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true})
    .then(function (response) {
        // resolves with the match regardless of query string
    });
```

See [MDN docs for Cache.match parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Cache/match#Parameters).